# jQuery Deferred not working as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery, deferred

This is my first time using `$.Deferred();` and it's proving to be a mission.

I have read [jQuery Deferred not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4979258/jquery-deferred-not-working), but that applies to ajax events, so doesn't really help in my case.

I have the following code in javascript:

```
var deferred = $.Deferred();

deferred.done(function() {
    console.log(auth.loggedIn);
    if(auth.loggedIn) {
        app.page = 'usr/dashboard';
    }
}

deferred.resolve(auth.initialize());
```

My `auth` object looks like this:

```
var auth = {

    loggedIn:false,

    initialize:function() {
        var data = {
            'login_token':app.getCookie('login_token'),
            'usr_id':app.getCookie('usr_id'),
            'source':config.source,
            'language_code':config.language_code,
            'country_code':config.country_code
        }
        app.api('usr/loggedin',data,function(data) {
            var response = JSON.parse(data);
            if(!response.result) {
                auth.loggedIn = false;
            }
            auth.loggedIn = true;
            console.log(auth.loggedIn);
        },'post');
    }
}
```

Now, if I `console.log(response)` in the `app.api` callback, the response is exactly what I expect it to be, if I `console.log(auth.loggedIn)` I get `true`.

If I `console.log` in `deferred.done` and `console.log(auth.loggedIn)` (in `initialize` I get two different values. What am I doing wrong and how can I make my app wait for `auth.loggedIn` to be set?

### UPDATE

This is how I am now doing it in my main file:

```
auth.initialize().done(function(auth) {
    if(auth.loggedIn) {
        app.page = 'usr/dashboard';
    }
    jsRouter.initialize();
});
```

jsRouter is based on [this 20 line javascript router](http://joakimbeng.eu01.aws.af.cm/a-javascript-router-in-20-lines/) and now only sometimes shows the template page, regardless of the page I am on.

The `jsRouter.initialize` function looks like this:

```
initialize:function() {
    window.addEventListener('hashchange',jsRouter.router);
    window.addEventListener('load',jsRouter.router);

    /* ERROR PAGES */
    jsRouter.route('404','errors/404',function() {});
    jsRouter.route('500','errors/500',function() {});

    /* ACTUAL PAGES */
    jsRouter.route('/','home',function() {});
    jsRouter.route('/home','home',function() {});
    jsRouter.route('/usr/register','usr/register',function() {});
    jsRouter.route('/usr/login','usr/login',function() {});
    jsRouter.route('/usr/forgotpassword','usr/forgotpassword',function() {});
    jsRouter.route('/usr/activate','usr/activate',function() {});
    jsRouter.route('/usr/dashboard','usr/dashboard',function() {});
    jsRouter.route('/adr','adr/index',function() {});
},
```

I have updated my `app.api` callback to look exactly like what [Felix King](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31268782/jquery-deferred-not-working-as-expected/31268887#31268887) suggested.

Comment: I think you make deferred in your `app.api` call, assuming it's AJAX call.

Comment: It seems that you should `return` the result of calling `app.api` but you are not, which causes the promise to be resolved with an undefined payload.

Comment: app.api looks like it could be Asynchronous Javascript ... is it?

Comment: `app.api` is a function which uses ajax to make calls to an API.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are currently resolving the deferred object with `undefined`, which does not make sense. You are also resolving it before the `app.api` callback was executed. 
The deferred object has to be resolved by the asynchronous callback.

`auth.initialize` should return the deferred object / promise, and you have to resolve it in the `app.api` callback:

```
var auth = {

    loggedIn:false,

    initialize:function() {
       var deferred = new $.Deferred();          // <- create deferred object
        var data = {
            'login_token':app.getCookie('login_token'),
            'usr_id':app.getCookie('usr_id'),
            'source':config.source,
            'language_code':config.language_code,
            'country_code':config.country_code
        }
        app.api('usr/loggedin',data,function(data) {
            auth.loggedIn = JSON.parse(data).result;
            deferred.resolve(auth);              // <- resolve when response was received
        },'post');
        return deferred.promise();               // <- return promise
    }
}

auth.initilize().done(function(auth) { 
  // at this point the login succeeded (or failed)
});
```

Comment: Was just writing the same answer.

Comment: Now my router, based on http://joakimbeng.eu01.aws.af.cm/a-javascript-router-in-20-lines/ and called after `if(auth.loggedIn) {}` only sometimes shows the template page.

Comment: Updated my question to make it more clear after this answer

Comment: This is jQuery, therefore `return deferred.promise();` (it's a method, not a property).

Comment: @Roamer-1888: Thanks. Wasn't sure anymore. Fixed.

Comment: It's very confusing especially if you move between Q and jQuery. Also, should `auth.loggedIn = true;` not be in an `else` clause, or something more concise?

Comment: @Roamer-1888: Right, fixed as well. Didn't pay too much attention to the actual logic.

Comment: Answered helped a lot. Thanks. Solved my issue with the router by just calling it before doing the auth.